# "Send Email" functionality for public web-site

Tags: html, captcha, sendmail

Public web-site provides list of employees to Internet visitors. Contact information is hidden but visitor can send email via popup email-form.

What do you think about automated-scripts/viruses/bot spam activity? Is Capture a "must" for this functionality and what kind of precautions can you suggest also?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth considering some basic obfuscation: use non-standard names for your form fields (e.g. don't just use "subject", "submit", etc). The less your form resembles a standard email submission form, the less likely standardised scripts will work for it. Of course, this will not stop a determined spammer. You might also want to prevent the email submission page from being indexed by search engines to make it harder for the spammers to find in the first place.

I would also say that a captcha (or recaptcha) is very important.

Comment: Thank you for the most detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

A CAPTCHA is probably good idea -- just to avoid messages from dumb bots probing out your form.  Without one, your users will probably end up getting a bunch of annoying messages.

Other than ensuring that it's actual person submitting the form, there's not much else that comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you, but how smart are modern bots? For example if I use jquery/ajax code to show popup dialog do they smart enough to parse this?

If I have postback form address - what's the best way to prevent (or minimize) "bad persons" intention to automatically send post request with email data via automated script (not a form).

Comment: Generating the form dynamically via Javascript could be a very smart way to fool most bots out there.  If the <form> tag doesn't appear in the page source directly, I suspect bot's (generally speaking) won't find it.  Good thinking!

Comment: I'm not going to construct full html form layout programmatically, just going to load it with ajax :) Anyway, thank you for your answer.